CakePHP 5.x: double leftJoinWith()
In my application ActivitiesCategories have (hasMany) Activities and Activities have (belongsToMany with a joinTable) Patients:
class ActivitiesCategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
    // ...

        $this->hasMany('Activities', [
            'foreignKey' => 'activities_category_id',
        ]);

    // ...
    }
}


class ActivitiesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
    // ...

        $this->belongsTo('ActivitiesCategories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'activities_category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('Patients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'activity_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'patient_id',
            'joinTable' => 'patients_activities',
        ]);

    // ...
    }
}


class PatientsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
    // ...

        $this->belongsToMany('Activities', [
            'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'activity_id',
            'joinTable' => 'patients_activities',
        ]);

    // ...
    }
}

Now, for each category and for each patient I want to know how many activities in total and how many activities in which that patient participated.
For example:

in the month of May 2024 Mark participated in 12 sports activities out
of a total of 15 (therefore absent from 3)

So I'm trying to follow the CookBook as indicated here.
So now let's go in order. To get the total activity for each category I do this:
(the find betweenDateTime method uses the $StartOn and $EndOn arguments to limit activity dates)
$Query = $this->Activities->ActivitiesCategories->find();
$results = $Query
    ->select([
        'name',
        'total_activities' => $Query->func()->count('Activities.id'),
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('Activities', function (SelectQuery $Query) use ($StartOn, $EndOn): SelectQuery {
        return $Query->find('betweenDateTime', StartOn: $StartOn, EndOn: $EndOn);
    })
    ->groupBy(['ActivitiesCategories.id'])
    ->orderByAsc('name')
    ->all();

This works correctly and the total_activities property tells me, for each category, the number of activities between $StartOn and $EndOn.
Now the patients. I add a second leftJoinWith():
$Query = $this->Activities->ActivitiesCategories->find();
$results = $Query
    ->select([
        'name',
        'total_activities' => $Query->func()->count('Activities.id'),
        'total_for_patient' => $Query->func()->count('Patients.id'),
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('Activities', function (SelectQuery $Query) use ($StartOn, $EndOn): SelectQuery {
        return $Query->find('betweenDateTime', StartOn: $StartOn, EndOn: $EndOn);
    })
    ->leftJoinWith('Activities.Patients', function (SelectQuery $Query) use ($patientId): SelectQuery {
        return $Query->where(['Patients.id' => $patientId]);
    })
    ->groupBy(['ActivitiesCategories.id'])
    ->orderByAsc('name')
    ->all();

Something strange happens here: the total_for_patient property (relative to the second leftJoinWith() I added) reports the correct count.
But the previous hour reports a result that seems almost random (unpredictable).
What am I doing wrong? How should i do? Thank you.
EDIT
I forgot: obviously I wonder if and how it is possible to do this using a single query or in any case limiting the queries.  Obviously I know that I could easily make two separate queries
